# Use cases for RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Can anyone tell me what are the use cases for `RxJava` in `Android`?

I have gone through a couple of tutorials they all provide explanations about how it works but nobody has provided what are use cases of RxJava in Android.

**So Where & in which components can I use RxJava in Android ?**

Comment: Have a look at my presentations specifically about this subject https://www.slideshare.net/MaximVolgin/rxjavaandroid and https://www.slideshare.net/MaximVolgin/rxjavadaug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what are the use cases for RxJava in Android?

First and foremost, many places where you have a background thread in Android, you can use RxJava to replace the thread (or `AsyncTask` or whatever). This includes:

- Disk I/O
- Network I/O
- `ContentResolver` requests of content and document providers
- Database access
- And so on

Secondarily, you may be able to manage other incoming sources of data as event streams via RxJava, such as input events (see RxBinding).

> in which components can I use RxJava in Android ?

Few `ContentProvider` implementations will use RxJava, as they expose a synchronous API. Few `BroadcastReceiver` instances will live long enough for RxJava to be useful. So, mostly, RxJava will be in support of activities and services, though the actual RxJava code may reside in other classes used by activities and services (e.g., view-models, presenters, repositories).

Answer (score 0):

Reactive programming have advantages when you work with asynchronous data streams.